# Cannot map a hotkey on my keyboard (XF86Mail)

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb

I had the following problem:

I wanted to make use of some Hotkeys on my keyboard (I am using Openbox, but it should not make a difference.)

Most of my keybinds worked just fine (XF86AudioRaiseVolume, XF86AudioLowerVolume, etc.).

However, I got no response to
XF86Mail

Answer (score 1):

1) Using `xev` I found that the key does work.

2) Inspecting the output of `xev` for known "good" keys, and not-working ones (`XF86Mail`), I found a difference:

Works in keybind:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
    root 0x1e3, subw 0x0, time 70102367, (1618,-868), root:(3219,29),
    state 0x10, keycode 158 (keysym 0x1008ff2e, XF86WWW), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Does not work in keybind:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
    root 0x1e3, subw 0x0, time 70103895, (1618,-868), root:(3219,29),
    state 0x10, keycode 223 (keysym 0x1008ff19, XF86Mail), same_screen YES,
--> XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 163
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

So, there is a plethora of options to choose from:

1. keycode: 163 (0xA3)
2. keycode: 223 (0xDF)
3. "XF86Mail"

Tried all of them, and the only one working was `0xDF`. (`<keybind key="0xDF">` in the openbox config)

Judging by the numbers, since the XF86WWW has the keycode 158, XF86Mail, the key next to it on the keyboard would probably had originally the keycode 163, but then a software layer changed it.

I started to dig into stuff like `xmodmap`, and an [archwiki guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Extra_Keyboard_Keys_in_Xorg), but then I did not have to understand whatever is going on, `xev` alone gave me the solution, once I was able to understand it.